# How to reduce the app size in Expo project?

Tags: react-native, build, expo

I've been learning React Native and Expo for a while now. I currently have a simple mobile application that only has four screens and no static documents other than icons and a splash screen. However, when I build the app in release mode for my iPhone, the app size is 518MB. Is there anything I can do to reduce the app size?

I have researched several methods to reduce the app size, but I haven't found a realistic or effective solution yet. I tried analyzing the app's package content, which showed that the React Native and Expo libraries were the main contributors to the large app size. However, I have not attempted any optimizations myself.

Comment: **I solved my problem by disabling hermes in ios/Podfile `:hermes_enabled => false`**